# Disable Cloudlfare SSL on nginx to use certificate

Tags: nginx, ssl, wordpress, cloudflare

I use Nginx to host a wordpress site which is configured to use exclusively SSL. A while ago, I activated the Strict SSL option and the HSTS option from Cloudflare.

Now I want to disable it and only use my SSL certificate. The thing is that if I disable SSL and HSTS from Cloudflare, I get a "too many redirection" error when I try to visit my website.

I removed the cookies from my browser and refreshed the page but it still gives me the same error. I don't remember having done anythong special on my Nginx config before enabling HSTS ans SSL on Cloudflare, but I guess this redirection issue comes from Nginx.

How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess with the tiny amount of information you've given is that HSTS is still in effect, and that by disabling HTTPS on CloudFlare you've told the website it must be HTTPS and forced CloudFlare to only support HTTP. I suggest turning HTTPS back on in CloudFlare.

You can't use your own HTTPS certificate if CloudFlare is in front of your website providing CDN features - CloudFlare terminates all connections using its own certificates, at least under the free plan. If you turn CloudFlare off (orange cloud changes to grey in your DNS page) then CloudFlare acts only as DNS and browsers contact your website directly. This is the only way to use your own certificate - basically turn CloudFlare off.

Another option is that either the site wide setting or a page rule is specifying the wrong kind of connection between CloudFlare and your website. Strict vs full vs flexible. This has caught me out once or twice.

If you post a link to your site we could have a look at what's actually going on.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use custom certificates on Cloudflare paid plans: Business or Enterprise. Check here: https://www.cloudflare.com/plans/

Answer (score -2):

You need to set Cloudflare SSL as Full (strict). Has worked in my case with letsencrypt.org.